# Javascript test ( object && object !== "null" && object !== "undefined" )

Tags: javascript

I seem to be using this test a lot

```
if( object && object !== "null" && object !== "undefined" ){
    doSomething();
}
```

on `objects` I get back from a service call or from reading cookies (since different browsers return the different values `null`, `undefined`, `"null"`, or `"undefined"`).

Is there an easier/more efficient way of doing this check?

Comment: If it actually may have the string values `"null"` and `"undefined"`, then your method can't be any simpler.

Comment: It does sometimes have the strings `"null"` or `"undefined"`.  Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: You can also use `!!` like `if(!!myobj){doSomething();}` to check the object. It converts the object to boolean and then inverts it again. Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10597474) answer for a very good explanation  .

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I don't think you can make that any simpler, but you could certainly refactor that logic into a function:

```
function isRealValue(obj)
{
 return obj && obj !== 'null' && obj !== 'undefined';
}
```

Then, at least your code becomes:

```
if (isRealValue(yourObject))
{
 doSomething();
}
```

Comment: I like your answer because it's reusable and **very** readable.  However, I just found a _slightly_ more efficient way of doing the actual check.

Comment: But: what if the object is a boolean and false?

Answer (score 11):

If you have jQuery, you could use `$.isEmptyObject()`.

```
$.isEmptyObject(null)
$.isEmptyObject(undefined)
var obj = {}
$.isEmptyObject(obj)
```

All these calls will return true. Hope it helps

Comment: Don't answer JavaScript questions with jQuery. jQuery isn't backwards compatible with JavaScript, it constantly changes breaking things posted, you save 1KB here or there by dumping 70KB on the client when their browser can already handle *real* JavaScript and it has horrible performance compared to knowing how to program competently.

Answer (score 5):

```
if(!!object){
  doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If `object` is truthy, we already know that it is not `null` or `undefined` (assuming that the string values are a mistake). I assume that a not `null` and not `undefined` test is wanted.

If so, a simple comparison to `null` or `undefined` is to compare `!= null`.

```
if( object != null ){
    doSomething();
}
```

The `doSomething` function will run only if `object` is neither `null` nor `undefined`.

Comment: No: "It does sometimes have the strings "null" or "undefined"." This won't work if the value has a REAL string in it: http://jsfiddle.net/7eYKN/1/

Comment: @aquinas: I saw that comment under the question, but didn't have enough rep to reply. The question would be then what is meant by "sometimes". I think the asker is giving us some impressionistic code instead of actual representation of code. Yes, a person may sometimes want to compare to the `"null"` string, but that's hardly a common scenario, but it is more common to see the `"undefined"` string because of `typeof foo === "undefined"`. So my answer tries to get at the core of what is usually wanted since the question doesn't seem to represent any common real world example.

Comment: @aquinas: If I had more rep, I'd also comment that SnakeEyes code will always give a `true` result.

Comment: Oh, I missed that about the cookies. Must be a stringified value. I think your answer to DRY it with a function is probably the best solution if that's the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe like this:

```
var myObj = {};
var isEmptyObj = !Object.keys(myObj).length;

if(isEmptyObj) {
    // true
} else {
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe like this

```
   if (typeof object !== "undefined" || object !== null)
    // do something
```

Comment: This isn't equivalent to the original function is it? He is specifically checking for a string with the value of "null". See: http://jsfiddle.net/7eYKN/

Comment: object is not a reserved word.

Comment: @SnakeEyes - That link you posted is terrible... not sure where they got their information from! Half of the words listed are not reserved words, and some of them are but are listed wrongly (e.g. `instanceOf` instead of `instanceof`). I'd stay away from that site if I were you.

Comment: @JamesAllardice then I will make mymown list of js reserved keywords using best books. :)

Comment: @SnakeEyes - See the link to the spec in my first comment. That contains the actual official list of reserved words!

Answer (score 2):

This should work without any issue.

```
if(object){ // checks for null and undefined
    doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to check if an object is empty is by using a utility function like the one below.

**create a function**

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
    for(var key in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Use above function following way:-**

So if you have an empty object, you can check whether it is empty by using the above function.

```
var myObj = {}; // Empty Object
if(isEmpty(myObj)) {
    // Object is empty (Would return true in this example)
} else {
    // Object is NOT empty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could simplify a bit your logic with the following:

```
if (object != null && typeof(object) == "object") {
    doSomething();
}
```

The main problem is that if you just check `typeof(object) == "object"`, it will return `true` if `object` is `null` since `null`'s type is `"object"`. However, if you first check that `object != null`, you can be sure you are having something that is neither `undefined` nor `null`.

Answer (score 0):

another simple way is

```
if (eval(object)) doSomething();
```

You can use eval to cast any type including string and be executed by javascript, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) is eval documentation

Answer (score 0):

If you want an `Object`, that is not an `Array`, and is not `null`, you might have to do some work, as all 3 will have the same `typeof` value.

```js
if (
  typeof maybeObject === 'object' 
  && maybeObject !== null 
  && !Array.isArray(maybeObject)) {
}
```