# checking Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have this piece of code where I check if hostel.country.address is null but nevertheless

```
return hostel.country.address &&
               hostel.country.address.internalEmployeeIdentifier !== null ||
               hostel.country.address.externalEmployeeIdentifier !== null;
```

I have this compilation problem on

```
hostel.country.address



Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.


- error TS2533: Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.
```

Comment: Try this: return hostel && hostel.country && hostel.country.address &&
               hostel.country.address.internalEmployeeIdentifier !== null ||
               hostel.country.address.externalEmployeeIdentifier !== null;

Comment: The compiler tells you exactly what you need to look into: that there are cases where `hostel.country.address` may be null or undefined. Is that expected?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript test ( object && object !== "null" && object !== "undefined" )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535403/javascript-test-object-object-null-object-undefined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use optional chaining (you should install the babel plug in)
and then your code will be something like:

```
hostel?.country?.address
```

more information can be found at:

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining

installation:
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining#installation

settings .babelrc

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return hostel.country.address &&
               hostel.country.address!.internalEmployeeIdentifier !== null ||
               hostel.country.address!.externalEmployeeIdentifier !== null;
```

should work.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```js
const address = hostel?.country?.address
return address?.internalEmployeeIdentifier !== null || address?.externalEmployeeIdentifier !== null
```

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this, then modify your return line to use it:

```
function isValid(test) {
    return !(test === null || test === undefined);
}
```

Your return could look like:

```
return isValid(hostel) && 
       isValid(hostel.country) && 
       isValid(hostel.country.address) &&
       (isValid(hostel.country.address.internalEmployeeIdentifier) ||
        isValid(hostel.country.address.externalEmployeeIdentifier));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have nested properties and parent property may or may not exist, it is good to take help of some external library. something like this can make it much simpler

```
const _ = require('lodash');
if(_.get(hostel, 'country.address.externalEmployeeIdentifier')) {
  // do something
}
```

this way you do not need multiple && conditions. The library will take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

One more way is to use object destructuring with default values.

```
  const {
    country: {
      address: { internalEmployeeIdentifier, externalEmployeeIdentifier } = {}
    } = {}
  } = hostel || {};

  return (
    internalEmployeeIdentifier !== null || externalEmployeeIdentifier !== null
  );
```